# Unable to find_element_by_id when element is created via execute_script

Tags: python, selenium

I am currently using python 3.6.5, [selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium) version 3.14.0

If I created a web element like the following:

```
driver.execute_script("""var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);var div = document.createElement('div');div.setAttribute('id', 'ZZZ');body.appendChild(div);""")
```

I wasn't able to use something like the following:

```
    wait.until(
        expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located(
            (By.ID, 'ZZZ')
        )
    )
```

I have double checked that the element is successfully created but using the APIs provided by the selenium package (e.g. find_element_by_id, and scripts like above) I wasn't able to locate the element.

Question: Is there something else I need to do after injecting new elements after execute_script? or currently, it is not possible?

I can get the element via the following though:

```
new_element = driver.execute_script('return document.getElementById("ZZZ");')
```

But this will be difficult for me if I couldn't use the default APIs provided by the selenium package (e.g. find_element_by_id)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below code works for me:

```
driver.get('http://www.google.com')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
driver.execute_script("var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);var div = document.createElement('div');div.setAttribute('id', 'ZZZ');body.appendChild(div);")

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ZZZ"))
)
driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Once the [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) is successfully created and further if you want to validate the presence of the added element within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) you can `print()` the **outerHTML** of the element using the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  driver=webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get('http://www.google.com')
  elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
  driver.execute_script("var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body').item(0);var div = document.createElement('div');div.setAttribute('id', 'ZZZ');body.appendChild(div);")
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ZZZ")))
  print(element.get_attribute("outerHTML"))
  driver.quit()
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  <div id="ZZZ"></div>
  ```