# Python selenium add li to ul

Tags: python, selenium

I have this html code

```
<ul class="select-items">
     <li class="select-items-item" data-label="<first>">Number 1</li>
</ul>
```

and I want to add a new li like `<li class="select-items-item" data-label="<second>">Number 2</li>`

What i tried so far :
I click the list using the xpath ( that works fine because I can see the list open),
addAttribute to the element (that is the tricky part, not working),
add javascript code ( not working either)

```
liItem = """
     var ul = document.getElementByXpath('//*[@class="select-items"]');
     var li = document.createElement("li");
     li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Element 4"));
     ul.appendChild(li);
 """
 driver.execute_script(liItem);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Suggestions about what? What is your question? Where is your code?

Comment: Edited with some code. As there are some people replying, I believe that the question is clear.

Comment: @mnmbs Please don't append the works/snippets from the well researched answers within your original questions.

Comment: Excuse me? That was not your answer. That was a snippet I wrote and did not work. I had this guy @JaSON that asked for code, so I delivered. Your snippet looks similar but you use different functions to create the li. Please see again the snippets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the following `<li>` i.e.

```
<li class="select-items-item" data-label="<second>">Number 2</li>
```

You can use the following line of code:

```
scriptTxt = """
    var ul = document.getElementsByClassName('select-items').item(0);
    var li = document.createElement('li');
    li.setAttribute('textContent', 'Number 2');
    ul.appendChild(li);body.appendChild(li);
"""
driver.execute_script(scriptTxt)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Unable to find_element_by_id when element is created via execute_script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397446/unable-to-find-element-by-id-when-element-is-created-via-execute-script/52398230#52398230)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Shouldn't it be  ```div.setAttribute``` instead of ```li.setAttribute```?

Comment: @mnmbs You are adding a `<li>` with _textContent_ as **Number 2** but not a `<div>` really.

Comment: I see. So with ```li.setAttribute('textContent', 'Number 2');``` I set the textContent of the li created at the line before that.

Comment: Unfortunately, I get this error Message: javascript error: li is not defined

Comment: @mnmbs, there was a simple mistake in `scriptTxt`. I edited the answer. Instead of `var div = ...` with `var li = ...`

Comment: Thats what I meant with my first comment (which now I see that wrote in the reverse order). Anyway. It now compiles but adds nothing to the list. I am investigating a little bit.

Comment: There was a mistake at the class name in my program. Now everything is ok. Thank you

Comment: Also for the snippet to be 100% accurate you need to add this ```        li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number 2"));``` otherwise there is no text for the li. Last but not least see the comment I added under my original post because you misunderstood my example.

Comment: @mnmbs Apologies, I must have overlooked the fineprints of the code. Reverted back your question.

Comment: @mnmbs Can you try the updated answer anw and let me know if that works seamless?

Comment: You need to remove ```body.appendChild(li);``` because it is not found. Also if you don't add ```li.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Number 2"));``` the li has no text and is not showing.

Comment: @mnmbs `body.appendChild(li);` was edited long ago :)

Comment: hi what is the accurate script, I am facing the issue.